# Apple/Safari issue playing background video on mobile device

Tags: javascript, ios, video

I have a site with full screen background video using BigVideo.js. (http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) On mobile devices, android is working great. However, on an apple device the video loads with a 'Play' button that you need to click which loads the video in a modal window over top of the site. Any ideas on how to make this behave like desktop/android devices where the video seamlessly plays in the background? Could there be an Apple app-driven event detecting video and forcing play in a modal?

Example HTML:

```
<div class="screen" data-video="vid/1-Statue.mp4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many mobile devices do not support video autoplay - the idea is to avoid users running up large mobile data bills. Last time I looked all the smaller iOS devices, i.e. iPhones did not.

There is a popular javascript library to detect browser features which includes a test for autoplay which may be useful for you:

- https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/video/autoplay.js

Similarly, inline video is not supported on all Mobile devices - it is evolving so more devices do now but it is probably not a good idea to rely on it. Again, there is at least one open source library trying to address this on iPhone (inline video works on iPads last time I checked, as far as I recall):

- https://github.com/newshorts/InlineVideo

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will probably just rely on showing a background video on iOS devices.